# How to fix when deleted folder /var/lib/* in CentOS 6

Tags: linux, centos, centos6

How to fix when deleted folder `/var/lib/*` on CentOS 6?

```
rpm -q centos-release yum rpm python

package centos-release is not installed

package yum is not installed

package rpm is not installed

package python is not installed
```

Comment: a) It's difficult to understand your question and b) Try [Super User](http://www.superuser.com/).

Comment: unfortunately, I deleted folder /var/lib/* in centos 6

how to recovery folder /var/lib/* in centos 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstall Centos 6, and then stop deleting important directories